# Do different types of MOs have different occupancies?

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, molecular-orbital-theory

There was a question in my textbook regarding the number of electrons in a molecular orbital.

> The maximum number of electrons in a sigma, pi, and delta molecular orbital are respectively?

Now, I believe that any molecular orbital can be occupied by a maximum of two electrons, and so the answer might be 2 electrons for sigma, 2 electrons for pi, and also 2 for delta orbital.

Is my answer correct, or are there other concepts that need to be applied? Is it true that any molecular orbital can occupy a maximum of only 2 electrons? Or is it possible to have more than 2 electrons for delta molecular orbital?

Comment: Without knowing the question verbatim and its source (citation) it is basically impossible to answer this. In molecular orbital theory, essentially a restricted Hartree Fock approach, the answer is two for all. I am going to close this question so that an appropriate [edit] may be made.

Comment: I you don't know what was his point then how we are supposed to? Delta orbitals aren't special.

Comment: I got the point, but edited it just because it said the question needs clarity. I edited it so that others can find it easier to understand the question verbatim, which was a bit confusing earlier. Thanks .

Comment: If this friend has some scientific point to make, then it should be given. But an assertion that is not backed up by any facts is not helpful in explaining the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, note that the labels $\sigma$, $\pi$, and $\delta$ aren't universally applicable to MOs; it depends on the molecular geometry. These labels are mostly useful for linear molecules. Non-linear molecules often have MOs that are labelled differently. Methane is a decent example. Other examples include water and ammonia.

[image: MO diagram of methane]

Restricting ourselves to linear molecules, where the labels *do* apply: some of the confusion likely arises because of the "simplest" case of a homonuclear diatomic molecule ($\ce{X2}$), where $\sigma$ MOs are always "alone" and $\pi$ MOs always come in pairs.

[image: MO diagram of a generic homonuclear diatomic]

So it's tempting to think that $\pi$ MOs can fit four electrons. This is not correct, though. The fact is that there are **two** $\pi$ MOs that happen to have the same energy, and each can fit two electrons.

Every MO can contain up to two electrons, *period*.

(Well, at least at this level of knowledge. If you are doing electronic structure theory, you may find that this statement is oversimplified; but you can work that out for yourself.)

Pictures are taken from Housecroft & Sharpe's *Inorganic Chemistry*, 4th ed.